# Is this good to use node modules package without declared in package.json

Tags: vue.js, lodash, node-modules

So i have vue project installed with vuetify. When i check in node_modules folder there is lodash installed too. So i import and use lodash in my component and it works properly. But this lodash package is not stated in my package.json. Is this good or not?

Comment: No. If the package that depends on Lodash stops using it, you have no Lodash.

Comment: Okay it make sense, thank you

Comment: Bad idea. Basically, if someone else tries to run your code, package.json will let npm know what modules to install. If you used a module that's not listed in package.json, it won't run, and your code will be judged as crap. :) \